# integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell, test

I have the following script that is trying to match and IP address with a value in a file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#To find the IP via ping
ping=$(ping federicolivieri.noip.me -c 1)
#To cut the result
ip=$(echo ${ping} | awk '{print $3}' | rev | cut -c2- | rev | cut -c2-)
#dnsdist variable
dnsdist_ip=$(awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/dnsdist/dnsdist.conf | cut -c 19- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev)

if [ "$ip" -eq "$dnsdist_ip" ]; then
   echo "ciao"
   else
   echo "newServer{address="`echo ${ip}`", name="raspi"}" >> /etc/dnsdist/dnsdist.conf
fi
```

However, when I run the script I get this error

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/myscripts# ./noip.sh
./noip.sh: line 10: [: 2.31.237.195: integer expression expected
```

I understood that the script expect a integer numeric value but as you know, IP address as "dots"

How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: For information about testing for string equality, see `man test`

Comment: or use plain old =

Comment: If the number of digits in your IP address ever changes, your `cut -c19-` will break. You'd be safer matching against the field name `address` like this - `dnsdist_ip=$(sed -n '$s!^.*address=\([1-9][0-9.]*\).*!\1!p' /etc/dnsdist/dnsdist.conf)`

Comment: Hi roaima,
The first 19 characters will never change because is a fix text, Anyway I take in account about your suggestion

Comment: @roaima is right, your `cut` usage here is brittle.  You're already using `awk` to grab only the first whitespace-separated field; why do you need to drop the last character of it?  (If you really *do* need to drop the last character, I'd still recommend ending that pipeline with the `awk` command and following up with `dnsdist_ip=${dnsdist_ip%?}` instead of the non-portable `rev`.)

Comment: Actually perhaps I misread the code...I guess you're dropping the first 18 characters, and the last *one* character?  But this is all in a single whitespace-delimited field that contains the IP address??  I *really* would like to see that line of your file....

Comment: @Wildcard there's an `echo >>` construct at the end of the code snippet that generates a new line in the file. That's what I based my proposed code change on.

Comment: @Wildcard
This is the string 
newServer{address=2.31.237.195, name=raspi}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Archemar pointed out in his comment, you want to use `=` for string comparison:

```
if [ "$ip" = "$dnsdist_ip" ];
```

The `-eq` operator is for numerical comparison, as explained [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> n1 -eq  n2
>
> True if the integers n1 and n2 are algebraically equal; otherwise, false.

Since IPs are not integers (they also contain `.`), you can't use `-eq` to compare them.